# my div repositions once text is applied

Tags: css, html

I set up this div layout to be cursor responsive, and i was planning on later changing the font to appear hidden until hover, but now that I'm testing the waters with text in my divs they pop down to about the space of the div itself. here is the css..

-the css-

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body {
    background:#000;

}

.grid_0 {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    background:#000000;
    max-width:1000px;
    padding:auto;
margin:auto;
vertical-align:top;
}


.grid_1,
.grid_2,
.grid_3,
.grid_4,
.grid_5,
.grid_6,
.grid_7,
.grid_8,
.grid_9
{
    width:30%;
    height:30%;
    margin:.5% .5%;
    max-width:300px;
    max-height:300px;
    min-width:250px;
    min-height:250px;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:inline-block;

}

.grid_2,
.grid_3,
.grid_4,
.grid_5,
.grid_6,
.grid_7,
.grid_8,
.grid_9{
    background: rgba(51,51,51,1);

}
.grid_5:hover,.grid_9:hover {
    background: rgba(0,153,204,1);
    transition-property: background;

}
.grid_2:hover,.grid_6:hover,.grid_7:hover{
    background: rgba(51,204,51,1);
    transition-property: background;
}
.grid_3:hover,.grid_4:hover,.grid_8:hover{
    background: rgba(102,204,153,1);
    transition-property: background;
}

.img{
    width:100%;
}

.container {
    width:1000px;
    height:1000px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
strong {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:30px;
    color: rgba(51,51,51,1);
}
```

the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>


<body>


<div class="grid_0">

<div class="grid_1">
<img class="img" src="img/b2logo.png">
</div>

<div class="grid_2">
<p>
hello
</p>
</div>

<div class="grid_3">
<p>
hello
</p>
</div>

<div class="grid_4">
</div>

<div class="grid_5">
</div>

<div class="grid_6">
</div>

<div class="grid_7">
</div>

<div class="grid_8">
</div>

<div class="grid_9">
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post the HTML.

Comment: Just some remarks: grid_0 to me seems to be an overlay, in which case height, width, margin, padding, and maybe max-width all seem redundant since its top/right/bottom/left is at 0 which means 100% height/width already. Secondly grid_1-9 have width in %, so if you add text to them they start out at width:0 and reposition themselves depending on the length of the text up to max-width 300px

Comment: the problem seems to be when i add text, the div drops down a full level instead of being in line with the other divs

Comment: and the % is so it will be responsive. Its a learning process for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `vertical-align:top;` to your `grid_X` classes

Comment: @user2566346 Glad to help, I see you are new to SO so maybe you don't know this but it is useful to the community to mark your question as resolved by choosing an 'accepted answer' by clicking the green check mark next to the answer that helped resolved your issue. Also it is customary to up vote useful answers, so just keep that in mind.